# Angular5 HttpInterceptor depending on the result of an Observable

Tags: angular5, angular-http-interceptors, adal.js, angular-observable

I am trying to implement using Angular5 an `HttpInterceptor` to inject an Authorization header in all HTTP requests.

I rely on a third party library (ADAL, here called `AuthService`) that exposes a `acquireToken()` method to get the token to be used for Bearer authorization.

The problem is that `aquireToken()` returns an observable, and i have to subscribe to get the real string I need.

Therefore, my code never injects the header, i suppose because `next.handle()` is executed before `acquireToken()` returns any value.

How can i ensure that the next handler is called only after the token has been retrieved?

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import {AuthService} from 'mylibrary';

@Injectable()
export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private auth: AuthService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        let headers = req.headers || new HttpHeaders();

        this.auth.acquireToken(req.url)
            .subscribe((token: string) => {
                headers = headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
            });

        return next.handle(req.clone({ headers: headers }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This code will do the job, the trick is using `mergeMap`

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AdalService } from './adal.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';

@Injectable()
export class AdalInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private adal: AdalService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        // if the endpoint is not registered then pass
        // the request as it is to the next handler
        const resource = this.adal.GetResourceForEndpoint(req.url);
        if (!resource) {
            return next.handle(req.clone());
        }

        // if the endpoint is registered then acquire and inject token
        let headers = req.headers || new HttpHeaders();
        return this.adal.acquireToken(resource)
            .mergeMap((token: string) => {
                // if the user is not authenticated then drop the request
                if (!this.adal.userInfo.authenticated) {
                    throw new Error('Cannot send request to registered endpoint if the user is not authenticated.');
                }

                // inject the header
                headers = headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
                return next.handle(req.clone({ headers: headers }));
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello friend, I have a hard time understanding the use of the mergeMap operator, so much so that I get to this question looking for information everywhere. I understand that it is used to mix two or more observables and obtain only one. but I have seen codes where they use it with a single observable and that confuses me.

Comment: Just an FYI, add `return this.adal.acquireToken(resource).pipe(mergeMap(...))` if it's an observable.

Answer (score -2):

possible issue is here

```
 constructor(private auth: AuthService) { }
```

the provider is not available inside the interceptor

#### solution

use [Injector](https://angular.io/api/core/Injector) to inject your service

```
// 1. import the injector
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
// 2. create a constant of your service
private auth: AuthService;
// 3. add injector into contsructor; remove authService from constructor
constructor(private injector: Injector) { }
// 4. now create instance of your service inside intercept()
intercept() {
const auth = this.injector.get(AuthService);
// 5. now call method on this auth object
```